# Clion on linux closes on backspace/delete

Tags: linux, clion

I've downloaded clion and installed it on linux ubuntu to be able to use swift on linux. It works fine except for the fact that whenever I hit either the "*backspace*" or "*delete*" button, **it just closes**. No error message, nothing.

-- Edit --
I actually just tested some more and noticed that it closes on whatever input you give it... (as in random letters)

I've checked the keyboard shortcuts in the settings, but couldn't find anything that could cause this. Building and running the projects works, so I'm guessing it has nothing to do with a faulty installation...

What could cause this?

Comment: I am using CLion on Arch Linux and have no problem running it. Could you maybe specify the version of CLion you're running and maybe set up a Virtual Machine and test it on a different Linux "installation"?

Comment: The CLion version I'm using is 2017.3. I will try out the virtual machine this afternoon.

Comment: Also: I've tested CLion on other languages now and they work fine. So it does have something to do with the swift plugin or something connected to it. Swift version: 4.0.3-RELEASE for Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu